# URL breaks after reading an environment variable from a .json file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to be able to set environment variables at runtime and so I followed [this](https://www.technouz.com/5125/changing-angular-environment-variables-at-runtime/) tutorial. However, when I try to use a variable, the URL breaks and redirects me to e.g. *localhost:8080/index.html#/foo* instead of *localhost:8080/#/foo*. This happens when I try to use the variable as a class field:

```
export class CometdService implements OnDestroy {

  protected cometd: CometDExtended = new cometlib.CometD() as CometDExtended;

  private subscriptions: cometlib.SubscriptionHandle[] = [];

  apiUrl: string;

  constructor(private environment: AppConfigService, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.apiUrl = environment.config.apiUrl;
    this.cometd.configure('http://localhost:8080/cometd');

    this.startConnection();
  }
(...)
}
```

or pass it into a path like so:

```
export class CometdService implements OnDestroy {

  protected cometd: CometDExtended = new cometlib.CometD() as CometDExtended;

  private subscriptions: cometlib.SubscriptionHandle[] = [];

  constructor(private environment: AppConfigService, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.cometd.configure(`http://${environment.config.apiUrl}/cometd`);

    this.startConnection();
  }
(...)
}
```

but not when I just instantiate a variable in the constructor:

```
export class CometdService implements OnDestroy {

  protected cometd: CometDExtended = new cometlib.CometD() as CometDExtended;

  private subscriptions: cometlib.SubscriptionHandle[] = [];

  constructor(private environment: AppConfigService, private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    let apiUrl = environment.config.apiUrl;
    this.cometd.configure('http://localhost:8080/cometd');

    this.startConnection();
  }
(...)
}
```

Comment: If the env var has a trailing forwards slash, try removing it. If it doesn't have one, try adding it.

Comment: @adsy It didn't help.